# see spacing/new line characters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, special-characters

How can I preview a text with the new line characters represented in a way I can actually see them?

for example instead of:

```
bla bla
bla
...
```

I want to see something like

```
bla bla[\n]
bla[\r]
...
```

but I want to see what type of character is it, because some are \n and some are \r...

the reason for this is that I have two pieces of text that are apparently different when processed by a javascript syntax-highlighting function, but they actually have the same content.

I want to see if they really have different end of line characters

Comment: So you're looking for an editor that actively shows you newline characters? or a way of seeing them yourself via a replace or smth ?

Comment: something like `alert($(element).text());`  but with replaced characters

Comment: In php, `addcslashes($str, "\r\n");`

Comment: ok nvm, the problem was that the packed version of the script I'm using seems to have a bug and ignores certain spacing characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript:

```js
function raw(str){
    return str.replace(/\t/g,'\\t').replace(/\r\n/g,'\\r\\n').replace(/\r/g,'\\r').replace(/\n/g,'\\n');
}
```

If you don't care about `\t`, just remove it above.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your code in a `pre` element and use this code

```
$('pre').hover( 
    function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var txt = $this.text();
        $(this).html( txt.replace('\n','[\\n]\n','g').replace('\r','[\\r]\r','g') );
    },
    function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var txt = $this.text();
        $(this).html( txt.replace('[\\n]\n','\n','g').replace('[\\r]\r','\r','g') );
    }
 );
```

it will show the `\n` and `\r` when you hover over the `pre` element.

**Example at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/hYnbS/